# Passing variables to the Event Dispatch Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, event-dispatch-thread

My GUI locks up because I need to update it through the EDT, however, I need to also pass a variable that is being updates with the GUI:

```
while ((message = this.in.readLine()).startsWith("NUMPLAYERS"))
{
    numOfPlayers = Integer.parseInt(message.split(":")[1]);
    numPlayers.setText("There are currently " + numOfPlayers + " players in this game");
}
```

This does not work. I need to set the text in the EDT but I cannot pass numOfPlayers to it without declaring it as final (which I don't want to do, because it changed as new players join the server)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use a `final` temporary variable:

```
final int currentNumOfPlayers = numOfPlayers;
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       numPlayers.setText("There are currently " + 
               currentNumOfPlayers + " players in this game");
    }
});
```

Comment: In this case, it just needs the local variable to be defined at an appropriate point (and made final).

Answer (score 2):

You have to make it final or have the `Runnable` reference a field (class varable). If referencing a field make sure that it's thread safe (via synchronized or volatile).

Comment: How would I reference the class variable? That would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
while ((message = this.in.readLine()).startsWith("NUMPLAYERS")) {
    numOfPlayers = Integer.parseInt(message.split(":")[1]);
    final newText = "There are currently " + numOfPlayers + " players in this game";
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            numPlayers.setText(newText);
        }
    });
}
```

NOTE:  I assume that the OP has a good reason for not marking `numOfPlayers` as final, perhaps that it is changed later in the same `while` loop in code that's not relevant to the question, so not shown.  And thus that `numOfPlayers` is declared before the `while` loop.

Without this assumption, I wouldn't make the additional variable `newText`.

Comment: Missing String before badly capitalised newtext. Probably can make numOfPlayers itself final after putting declaration in the correct place.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin: I updated my answer ... the OP says that he has a good reason for not making numOfPlayers final.  I assume that this ties into why the OP's sample does not show the variable declaration.  And because you complained, I changed the capitalization of newText. :)

Answer (score 0):

Define this class outside of your method:

```
public abstract class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    protected int var;
    public MyRunnable (int var) {
        this.var = var;
    }
}

Now your code can look like this:
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new MyRunnable(5) {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //numPlayers.setText("There are currently " + var + " players in this game");
    }
});
```

(For the purposes of this example, I am assuming that there is a good reason why using a locally scoped final temp variable will not work.  I honestly can't think of any reason for that restriction, though.)